# Writing a Java program, Java can't find my symbol in an array?. Need help

Tags: java, arrays, compiler-construction, methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java can't find symbol, Java can't find my symbol in an array?.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964190/java-cant-find-symbol-java-cant-find-my-symbol-in-an-array)

i get this error 
I'm making a GUI program, The problem i'm having is creating a code that when a user selects something a action happens.

for example, select a meal and the totalcharges changes to 2500.

```
Main.java:155: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable isSeletecd
location: class java.lang.String
if (dorm[0].isSeletecd && meal[0].isSeletecd())
           ^.
```

.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout; 
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent; 
import java.awt.event.ActionListener; 
import javax.swing.JButton; 
import javax.swing.JComboBox; 
import javax.swing.JFrame; 
import javax.swing.JLabel; 
import javax.swing.JPanel; 
import javax.swing.JTextField; 

/** 

The Main class creates the GUI for the Dorm and 
Meal charges. 
*/ 

public class Main extends JFrame 
{ 
private JPanel dormPanel; 
private JComboBox dormBox; 
private JPanel mealPanel; 
private JComboBox mealBox; 
private JPanel totalChargesPanel; 
private JPanel selectedMealPanel; 
private JPanel buttonPanel; 
private JButton calcButton; 
private JLabel label1; 
private JTextField totalCharges; 



private String[] dorm = { "Allen Hall: $1,500 per semester", 
"Pike Hall: $1,600 per semester", 
"Farthing Hall: $1,200 per semester", 
"University Suites: $1,800 pe r semester"}; 





private String[] meal = { "7 meals per week: $650 per semester", 
"14 meals per week: $1,095 per semester", 
"Unlimited meals: $1,500 per semester"}; 

/** 
Constructor 
*/ 
public Main() 
{ 
super("Dormitory and Meal Plan"); 

// Specify an action for the close button. 
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

// Create a BorderLayout manager. 
setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 

// Create the dorm and meal panel. 
buildDormPanel(); 
buildMealPanel(); 
buildSelectedTotalChargesPanel(); 
buildButtonPanel(); 

// Add the components to the content pane. 
add(dormPanel, BorderLayout.WEST); 
add(mealPanel, BorderLayout.EAST); 
add(totalChargesPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH); 
add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH); 

// Pack the contents of the window and display it. 
pack(); 
setVisible(true); 
} 

// The buildDormPanel method builds the dorm panel. 
private void buildDormPanel() 
{ 
// Create the dorm panel. 
dormPanel = new JPanel(); 
dormBox = new JComboBox(dorm); 

// Register the action listener. 
dormBox.addActionListener(new ComboBoxListener()); 

// Add the dorm panel to the panel. 
dormPanel.add(dormBox); 
} 

// The buildMealPanel method builds the meal panel. 
private void buildMealPanel() 
{ 
// Create the meal panel. 
mealPanel = new JPanel(); 
mealBox = new JComboBox(meal); 

// Register the action listener. 
mealBox.addActionListener(new ComboBoxListener()); 

// Add the meal panel to the panel. 
mealPanel.add(mealBox); 
} 

// The buttonPanel method builds the bottun panel. 
private void buildButtonPanel() 
{ 
// Create a panel. 
buttonPanel = new JPanel(); 

// Create a button. 
calcButton = new JButton("Calculate"); 

// Register an action listener with the button. 
calcButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener()); 

// Add the button to the panel. 
buttonPanel.add(calcButton); 
} 

// The buildSelectedDormPanel builds the selected totalCharges panel. 
private void buildSelectedTotalChargesPanel() 
{ 
// Create the totalChargesPanel for the label. 
totalChargesPanel = new JPanel(); 
label1 = new JLabel("Total charges per semester: "); 

// Create the totalCharges textfield. 
totalCharges = new JTextField (25); 
totalCharges.setEditable(false); 

// Add the totalChargesPanel to the panel. 
totalChargesPanel.add(label1); 
totalChargesPanel.add(totalCharges); 
} 

/** Private inner class that handles the event when the user 
selects the dorm and meal boxes. 
*/ 
private class ComboBoxListener implements ActionListener 
{ 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{ 
// Variables to hold the dorm, meal, and total charges. 
String dorm = (String) dormBox.getSelectedItem(); 
String meal = (String) mealBox.getSelectedItem(); 

// Calculates the total. 
totalCharges.setText(meal + dorm); 
} 
} 

private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener 
{ 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{ 
if (dorm[0].isSeletecd && meal[0].isSeletecd())
totalCharges.setText("2150.00");

if (dorm[0].isSeletecd && meal[1].isSeletecd())
totalCharges.setText("2595.00");

if (dorm[0].isSeletecd && meal[2].isSeletecd())
totalCharges.setText("3000.00");

if (dorm[1].isSeletecd && meal[0].isSeletecd())
totalCharges.setText("2250.00");

if (dorm[1].isSeletecd && meal[1].isSeletecd())
totalCharges.setText("2695.00");

if (dorm[1].isSeletecd && meal[2].isSeletecd())
totalCharges.setText("3100.00");

if (dorm[2].isSeletecd && meal[0].isSeletecd())
totalCharges.setText("1850.00");

if (dorm[2].isSeletecd && meal[1].isSeletecd())
totalCharges.setText("2295.00");

if (dorm[2].isSeletecd && meal[2].isSeletecd())
totalCharges.setText("2700.00");

if (dorm[3].isSeletecd && meal[0].isSeletecd())
totalCharges.setText("2450.00");

if (dorm[3].isSeletecd && meal[1].isSeletecd())
totalCharges.setText("2895.00");

if (dorm[3].isSeletecd && meal[2].isSeletecd())
totalCharges.setText("3300.00");
} 
} 

public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
new Main(); 
} 
}
```

Comment: Don't just repost the question.  If you have a problem understanding the answers, add comments.

Comment: I Just answered your question 4 hours ago. If you are still having problems try changing the question. tell us what you have tried, and what you are trying to accomplish. And please, for the love of god, read the http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @user599272 What are you trying to accomplish here at SO, more Downvotes than Questions?

Answer (score 1):

dorm is an array of String and the methods isSelected and setSelected (however you spell them) are meaningless for Strings.  Read the tutorial on how to use a JComboBox to learn how to properly use them. You can find it here: [How To Use ComboBoxes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)

Comment: Shoot, you've already been told this in a previous questions of yours, a recommendation you've chosen to ignore.  Why are you ignoring recommendations made in previous threads, and why should we continue to try to help you if you just ignore the help?  If you don't understand a reply, then say something, but don't just re-ask the question and make us waste our time.